# Citrix receiver client: Web interface - "You do not have the proper encryption level to access this session"

Tags: firefox, encryption, citrix, vdi, icaclient

I was using citrix receiver client (version 13.1) from my personal Ubuntu 14.04 machine to access my Windows 7 virtual work desktop.

Since a couple of weeks ago, i am getting "SSL Error 4" error and could not access the Windows 7 machine.

I anticipated more trouble and updated to citrix receiver version 13.5 to stay current.

Now I have two problems connecting to that Windows 7 machine:

1. Windows 7 session is not opening up as a stand-alone in citrix receiver and it is opening up as a new tab (web-interface) in Firefox (my regular browser).
2. As soon as i see the Windows 7 desktop in the Firefox tab, the session pops up this error: "you do not have the proper encryption level to access this session."
   I visited this site: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX124879

Though I understood the article, Firefox does not download a (sample file name) "xyz.ica" and so I am unable to make the changes suggested in the article. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:** The above mentioned point #1 cannot be fulfilled because there is no Citrix receiver launcher for Linux as mentioned in this link https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2017/03/15/firefox-52-and-citrix-receiver-for-web/

(Note: I did not delete point#1 for historical reasons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long break I tried it with Chrome and latest citrix receiver. To my surprise, it worked!!

I downloaded the latest Citrix receiver (version 13.6) for Linux (Released on 11th July 2017) from https://www.citrix.co.in/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html 
and I am able to open the virtual desktop using Citrix receiver with Chrome Version 60.0.3112.78.

Note: The issue mentioned as point#2 in my question still persists with Firefox.